# Kendo Grid hierarchy - passing row ID to nested grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have two Kendo Grids in asp.net.
Master grid with OpravneniId

```
@(Html.PageElement().Kendo().Grid(new DataTable())
        .Name("grid-opravneni")
        .DataSource(binding => binding
                    .Ajax()
                    .PageSize(20)
                    .Read(r => r.Action("DataForGrid", "Opravneni", new { poskytovatelId = Model.Id }))
                    .Model(model => model.Id("OpravneniId")))
                    .Columns(column =>
                    {
                        column.Bound("OpravneniId").Title("id");
                        column.Bound("Nazev").Title("Název");
                    })
                    .Pageable(paging =>
                            paging.PageSizes(new[] { 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000 }))
                    .Events(e => e.DetailInit("onDetailInit"))
)
```

Nested Grid, which uses OpravneniId to load data:

```
    @(Html.PageElement().Kendo().Grid(new DataTable())
            .Name("grid-mistoposkytovani")
            .DataSource(binding => binding
                                        .Ajax()
                                        .PageSize(20)
                                        .Read(r => r.Action("DataGridForOpravneni", "MistoPoskytovani", new { opravneniId = "#=OpravneniId#" }))
                                        .Model(model => model.Id("id"))
                                        )
            .Columns(column =>
            {
                column.Bound("Obec").Title("Obec").Template(@< text ></ text >).ClientTemplate("#=NazevObceSMoProPrahu#");
                column.Bound("Obec").Title("Obec").Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("#=NazevObceSMoProPrahu#");
                column.Bound("CastObce").Title("Část obce");
            })
            .Pageable(paging =>
            paging.PageSizes(new[] { 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000 }))
    )
```

Problematic part is this:

```
new { opravneniId = "#=OpravneniId#" }
```

When #=OpravneniId# is used in the master grid, it correctly display the ID, but when used in nested grid for data load, it's null.

Any idea how to get the ID from the master row and pass it to the DataSource Read method on nested grid?
The demo provided by telerik ( https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy ) uses different approach, I need to use .NET components.
Thank you.

Comment: Kendo also has ASP .NET guides: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/hierarchy

Comment: Well, that helped a lot. I even managed to nest third grid into the second one. Thank you. Would mark this as Answer, but it's just a comment.

Comment: Happy to help. Per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), single-link answers should be comments. If you're feeling like it, you can post a complete answer, I'm good with my small contribution. :)

Comment: @GaloisGirl the idea behind those guidelines is to avoid answers dependent on external links that can go dead and leave the answer void. You can copy paste the information from the link, reference it and formulate that as an answer so the OP can accept it. That way you can build up your reputation as well.